# how to retrieve records after 18:30:00 in php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to retrieve records after 6:30:00pm i.e 18:30:00 from the database.
i have tried this

```
SELECT  * 
FROM mytable
WHERE  `datetime` 
BETWEEN  '18:30:00'
AND  '23:59:00'
```

Output is nothing shown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this. Add TIME(table_name) around the table name.

```
SELECT  * 
FROM mytable
WHERE  TIME(datetime) 
BETWEEN  '18:30:00'
AND  '23:59:00'
```

Answer (score 2):

You may put the date as well since the value is datetime or else it will use default date

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
WHERE [datetime] >= '2016-03-11 18:30:00' 
AND [datetime] <= '2016-03-11 23:59:00'
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
WHERE TIME([datetime]) >= '18:30:00' 
AND TIME([datetime]) <= '23:59:00'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE  TIME(datetime) >= time '18:30:00';
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with php `getdate()` function.

```
$t = getdate();
if($t[hours] == 8 && $t[minutes] == 30 ){

    $mydata = 'select * from mytable';
}
```

..........
...........

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're going to be missing the last 59 seconds of the day with your current filter.  Surely it should be between `18:30:00` and `23:59:59`?

I.e.,

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
WHERE TIME([datetime]) >= '18:30:00' 
AND TIME([datetime]) <= '23:59:59'
```